# Blurred gif background with text on top in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a gif background set in my top row in my bootstrap container and I want to have some text on top but anytime I try to make the background blur, the text also blurs out.

I want the background to be blurred out but have the "Project 1" be fully visible without being blurred out.

Code:

```css
#header {
     background-image:url('https://developer.playcanvas.com/images/user-manual/scripting/go-to-anything.gif');
     background-size:cover;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     height: 234px;
}
#header-text {
     padding: 50px 0; 
     color: darkorange; 
     text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; 
     font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: darkseagreen">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
            <h1 id="header-text">Project 1</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another `div` element, like this:

(I also removed the inline styling, so CSS stays in CSS.)

```css
.container { /* From inline style */
  background-color: darkseagreen;
}

#header {
  position: relative; /* Added */
  /* Removed some other */
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 234px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#header-text {
  position: relative; /* Added */
  padding: 50px 0;
  color: darkorange;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  font-size: 80px;
}

/* Added all the below */
#header-back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-image: url('https://developer.playcanvas.com/images/user-manual/scripting/go-to-anything.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><!-- Removed the inline style that was there -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
      <div id="header-back"></div><!-- Added this -->
      <h1 id="header-text">Project 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks @takit

Answer (score 2):

It won't work because `blur` affects all child elements.

Instead, add the image to a pseudoelement and blur that instead.

Example:

```css
#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 234px;
  /* center text */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#header:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://developer.playcanvas.com/images/user-manual/scripting/go-to-anything.gif');
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  filter: blur(3px);
}

#header-text {
  color: darkorange;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  font-size: 80px;
  /* stack text above pseudoelement */
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="background-color: darkseagreen">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="header">
      <h1 id="header-text">Project 1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```